# El Capitan "Paste and Match Style" not working in Microsoft Word

Tags: keyboard, macos, ms-office, shortcut, microsoft

I want to set up my computer to paste unformatted text by default. When I try to do this (following the advise of several online guides) my paste no longer works. I went to keyboard > shortcuts > app shortcuts > +. See my changes below. When I try command+v in Microsoft Word, nothing happens. What went wrong here? Is there a way I can make this work in Microsoft Word?
[image]

Comment: Pro tip for screenshots of a window - after you hit cmd/shift/4 tap the spacebar & then the window you click in will be screen-snapped perfectly, including nice drop-shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.suppertime.co.uk/blogmywiki/2015/07/unformatted-paste/

First make a new macro in Word. Go to Tools > Macro > Macros… and make a new macro called PasteUnformatted.

Paste this code into the Visual Basic editor:

Sub PasteUnformatted()
Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteText
End Sub

Then remap the cmd+V shortcut by going to Tools > Customize Keyboard… then pick ‘Macros’ from the Categories list. Find PasteUnformatted and assign cmd-V to it, click on the ‘assign’ button, and now every time you press cmd-V it should paste unformatted text that matches the formatting of the new document you are working on.

Answer (score 2):

> When I try ctrl+v

<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Try to delete and add one again.

It works for me (macOS Sierra, Safari):
[image]

Comment: Did the checkmark appear for you? It still isn't working for me.

Comment: I'm mostly testing this with Microsoft word...

Comment: No, there is no checkmark

Comment: I see now. It works in most places but not in Microsoft Word.

Comment: Word doesn't use the command "Paste and Match Style" it uses "Paste and Match Formatting"

Answer (score 1):

The trick for any non-standard app is to set the key command for that app alone.
You also need to remove or alter any existing conflict [in this case  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd> ] so the simplest in this case seems to be to just swap them over.

The following seems to work just fine on Word 2011, can't test on any other versions

[BTW, Word doesn't appear in the list when you try to add it as an app - you have to use Other... & go find it in Applications]

[image]

*Edit*
... or perhaps not.
Paste and Match Formatting isn't the same as 'unformatted text'

I came up with this compromise

[image]

It's not a one-key fix, unfortunately -  though you can just hit [Down Arrow depending on the existing format the menu presents different options], Enter